# how to add routing functionalities on the top of veins appl?

Tags: omnet++, veins

Veins is easy to use the map with obstacles from SUMO. However, it lacks routing operations of communication networks. I want to add AODV routing on the top of Veins' examples. What is the straightforward way ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

INET 4 supports the simulation of routing protocols. I would therefore recommend to essentially build a simulation using INET 4, then to use Veins (and `veins_inet`) to drive node mobility/creation in your simulation. See the `veins_inet` example for how to do that.